# PMD issue and Java --version

Tags: salesforce, apex, pmd, java-home

I would like to know if this message is correct, when I write in cmd

> java --version

I add it in the path

[image]

I have some troubles with Salesforce extension [PMD](https://pmd.github.io) and shows the following message :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I also faced these warnings.

I created a starter project (java-17, maven, pmd, unit tests, log4j2).
https://github.com/yan-khonski-it/java-17-pmd

Instead of using a specific rule, I used category.

```
<rulesets>
  <ruleset>category/java/bestpractices.xml</ruleset>

  <!-- My own file with custom rules, you can remove it-->
  <ruleset>custom-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
</rulesets>
```

For example, in the plugin source code:

```
<!-- Rules, that have been moved into a category -->
```

and same applies to other categories / rule sets.

https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-java/src/main/resources/rulesets/java/junit.xml